# FedEx RateWebServiceClient issues. Error : RequestedPackageLineItem object cannot be null or empty

Tags: fedex

I am getting the following message:

> ERROR  Code: 992   Message: RequestedPackageLineItem object cannot be
>   null or empty.   Source: crs
>
> Notification no. 1   Severity: WARNING   Code: 870   Message: Service
>   type takes precedence over carrier codes; service type used to rate.
>   Source: crs

While using the `Fedex_ground` or other services except `FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY`. Its working fine with `FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY` but its giving an error when I am use the following services:

- FedEx Ground
- FedEx 2Day AM
- FedEx 2Day
- FedEx First Overnight
- FedEx Priority Overnight
- FedEx Standard Overnight
- FedEx Express Saver

Comment: Resolved the issues. Thank you !!

Comment: Glad this is resolved. Please post an answer to help others who may face this issue :)

Comment: Sure, Here is the little guidance and I will try to help regarding the same if needed

Comment: Actually the service for which it was working fine was a **FREIGHT** service of the fedex. And the fedEx RateWebService uses different functions for both Freight services like Fedex_freight_priority and other freight services. And it uses             
 `RateRequest.RequestedShipment.FreightShipmentDetail.LineItems` for freight services and I was using General Package Line Items so for that we need to set data in    `RateRequest.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems`

Comment: After that make sure to pass true values in all boolean var for those values that you are passing and make sure you are passing `GroupPackageCount="1" ` at least one so that it can identify there is package information. Then only you would be able to get Rates. I hope it would help you if you are facing issues with that.

Comment: @krishna-kumar : If possible, could you please share a complete RateRequest for FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY and FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY, so that others can see the minimum required key/param for a LTL Freight rate request?